# Ngnix Reverse Proxy With SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, web-server, proxy, ssl-certificate

I want to configure a proxy server with `Ngnix` to redirect to `https` server. The problem is that I don't have the private key of the `.crt` file of the web server which I have downloaded from the browser.

And when I run `Ngnix` it shows the following error:

> [emerg] no "ssl_certificate_key" is defined for certificate "webServer.crt"

**Ngnix.conf:**

`proxy_ssl_certificate    proxyServer.crt;
proxy_ssl_certificate_key proxyServer.key;
ssl_certificate webServer.crt;`

My Question :

1. I don't understand the logic behind that why the key is needed if the proxy server doesn't need to decrypt the message, Can I configure this without the webServer certificate key.
2. Can I use the same web server certificate to configure the proxy server "without key"

Answer (score 0):

the proxy server does need to decrypt.

perhaps you could set up IP forwarding instead of a proxy server.